Find and isolate the values found in a text column - DAX
I have a two dummy tables that look like:
Narrative
User
There is a 1- * relationship between them
I have created a measure so I can find what Users are mentioned in the Narrative, however the measure keeps returning null values. I tried using the FIND function and CONTAINSSTRING functions but it does not return values from the User column.
MatchedUsers = 
  VAR NarrativeText = MAX('Narrative'[Narrative])
  RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
      CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
          VALUES('User'[User]),
          NOT(ISBLANK(NarrativeText)) && 
          CONTAINSSTRING(NarrativeText, 'User'[User])
        ),
      'User'[User], ", "
    )
  )

Id like it to return the names from the user column that are mentioned in the Narrative column



Narrative
User




The tree is green



Tim's tree is green



Tim, Sarah, Anne, Fred
Sarah, Anne


Jack, Sarah
Jack, Sarah


It is sunny outside





Try this measure:
MatchedUsers = 
    VAR usersTable = ALL(User[User])  //Get all users
    VAR n = MAX(Narrative[Narrative]) //Gets the current Narrative
    
    VAR matches = CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(
        FILTER(
            usersTable,
            CONTAINSSTRING(n, [User]) //Finds each user in the Narrative
        ),
        [User], ", ") //Creates comma delimited list
    )
    RETURN matches


This works thanks!
